# How many pairs of intersecting intervals can be chosen from two finite sets of disjoint intervals?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, convex-geometry, bipartite-graphs

Let
$$ \mathcal{K} := \{ I \cap J \mid I \in \mathcal{I}, J \in \mathcal{J} \} \setminus \{ \emptyset\},$$
where $\mathcal{I}$ is a finite set of disjoint real intervals, and so is $\mathcal{J}$.

Obviously $| \mathcal{K}| \leq |\mathcal{I}| |\mathcal{J}|$. Are there any better bounds on the cardinality of $\mathcal{K}$?

Where in the literature can one find related theory and results?

Comment: Intervals of the real line?

Comment: Yes, real intervals.

Comment: Consider the bipartite graph with vertices $I\cup J$ and edges $(a,b)$ if $a$ intersects $b$.

Comment: Thanks @markvs. This still doesn't give me a better bound than the product of their cardinalities, but I believe one should exist. I'm unable to draw a complete bipartite graph that satisfies the assumptions above. There is something about the topology of the real line that prevents this, but I don't understand what or why.

Comment: If $a\in I$ then edges $(a,b)$ mean that either $b\subseteq a$ (and then $b$ is not connected to any $a'$) or $b$ contains $a$ (and then $a$ is not connected to any $b'\ne b$) or $b$ overlaps with $a$ (there are at most two such $b$).

Comment: @markvs right. At first it wasn't obvious why there were at most two such b, but I can see how to prove that. So we can initially ignore any a that is fully contained in some b, and any b that is fully contained in some a. Then each remaining node can have at most two edges, and we have a path graph with N-1 edges. The a and b that we initially left out just add one more edge each. Cheers!

Comment: This seems about right.

Comment: @markvs Please group your comments into an answer in order that the solution will be clear enough (as it has been said by Jacob Manaker, comments are not permanent and cannot be searched through Math SE Stack Exchange search tool)

Comment: You should edit the body of this Question to include the clarification that these are real intervals.  A family of disjoint real intervals is at most countable, so you might want to clarify whether families of only finite cardinality are considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the bipartite graph with vertices $\mathcal{I}∪\mathcal{J}$ and edges $(I,J)$ if $I$ intersects $J$.

If $I\in \mathcal{I}$ then edges $(I,J)$ mean that either $J\subseteq I$ (and then $J$  is not connected to any other $I′\in \mathcal{I}$) or $J$ contains $I$ (and then $I$ is not connected to any other $J′\in \mathcal{J}$) or $J$ overlaps with $I$ (there are at most two such $J$).

The rest was explained by @Selva:

So we can initially ignore any $I$ that is fully contained in some $J$, and any $J$ that is fully contained in some $I$. Then each remaining node can have at most two edges, and we have a path graph with no more than $N-1$ edges, where $N$ is the number of remaining nodes. The $I$ and $J$ that we initially left out just add one more edge each. It follows that $|\mathcal{K}| < |\mathcal{I}| + |\mathcal{J}|$.